# Angular get multiple apis and get from selector in combine latest or fork join operator

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

Issue is multiple times are triggering subscribe method need to avoid such thing.

With this all three selector at initial time combine latest called at once. But, the problem is on next time if it triggered combine latest subscribe method it trigger three times instead of 1 time.

And I tried with help of fork Join that not gonna help, even subscribe not trigger with fork Join

Please suggest which rxjs operator would help and get this cases

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js3ue.png)

```
 const volumeAccSub = this.store
        .select(fromSelectors.getVolumeAccContent)
        .pipe(filter(data => !!data));

    const volumeMaxSub = this.store
        .select(fromSelectors.getVolumeMaxContent)
        .pipe(filter(data => !!data));

    const flowRateAccSub = this.store
        .select(fromSelectors.getFlowRateAccContent)
        .pipe(filter(data => !!data));

    const mergedContentOps = combineLatest([
        flowRateAccSub,
        volumeAccSub,
        volumeMaxSub,
    ]).pipe(delay(2000)).subscribe(val => {
        this.formatContentReceived(val);
    });
```

Please suggest which rxjs operator would help and get this cases

Thank is advance

Comment: `combineLatest` will trigger once if only one of the sources emits a value (and will then use the existing values for the other 2 sources). If you are triggering an update which is changing all three of your selectors, then you are emitting a value in each of the sources, in which case `combineLatest` will correctly emit 3 emissions. Make sure that you are only triggering one emission, if this is not the case then your problem may be with your store structure/reducers. There are also operators like `throttle` or `debounceTime` if you genuinely want to update all 3 sources

Comment: @nate-kumar is right, about possibly using `debounceTime`. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74246377/1858357) explains that solution in more detail.

Comment: @nate-kumar please explain in more details. but reducers at initial time it should be null and once api data success data will store into reducers selector.
But How to avoid such cases. I mean in the above cases

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using ngrx and that you are trying to listen 3 selectors from the same state.

In this scenario the best solution is to create a selector that combine the 3 selectors and returns the data that you need in one emission, so you can subscribe just one observable.

example from [ngrx doc](https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-for-multiple-pieces-of-state):

```js
export const selectUser = (state: AppState) => state.selectedUser;
export const selectAllBooks = (state: AppState) => state.allBooks;
 
export const selectVisibleBooks = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  selectAllBooks,
  (selectedUser: User, allBooks: Book[]) => {
    if (selectedUser && allBooks) {
      return allBooks.filter((book: Book) => book.userId === selectedUser.id);
    } else {
      return allBooks;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: all three selector should be individual there is no relation with others but should combined and subscribe at once.